# Text replacing is not working

Tags: python

I have a list of integers that looks like:

i =   [1020 1022 .... ]

I need to open an xml file which is stored as .txt , where each entry includes

```
Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

I need to iterate through the records replacing each the numbers in "Keys1029" with the list entry. so that instead of having:

```
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

We have:

```
....Settings="Keys1020"/>
....Settings="Keys1022"/>
```

So far I have:

```
import os
out =   [1020,1022]
with open('c:\xml1.txt') as f1,open('c:\somefile.txt',"w") as f2:
    #somefile.txt is temporary file
    text = f1.read()
    for item in out:
        text = text.replace("Keys1029","Keys"+str(item),1)
    f2.write(text)
#rename that temporary file to real file
os.rename('c:\somefile.txt','c:\xml1.txt')
```

This is replacing:

```
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

with

```
....Settings="Keys1"/>
....Settings="Keys1"/>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: It sounds *almost* like you forgot `str(item)` and are instead using `text.replace('1029', 1)`. Your code as posted here actually works.

Comment: Well you are not iterating the input file.

Comment: I'm sorry The replacement line is actually: text = text.replace("Keys1029","Keys"+str(item),1) . I've fixed this above.

Comment: It turns out that you were right it does work as is. My mistake was in the input elsewhere in the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different and more robust algorithm:

```
text = """
bla bla bla 1029 and 1029
bla bla bla 1029
bla bla bla 1029 and 1029
"""
out = [1020,1022]
cnt_repl=0
while True:
    text_new = text.replace("1029", str(out[cnt_repl%(len(out))]),1)
    if text_new==text: break
    cnt_repl+=1
    text=text_new
print text
```

for the example text it returns:

```
bla bla bla 1020 and 1022
bla bla bla 1020
bla bla bla 1022 and 1020
```